# Error while installing TextBlob

Tags: python, textblob

I am trying to install `TextBlob`. As per the official doc, i did this.

```
> pip install -U textblob
> python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

The `pip` command is doing its job. But the other command is giving following error.

> [nltk_data] Error loading brown: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.
>
> [nltk_data] Error loading punkt: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.
>
> [nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.
>
> [nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: HTTP Error 405:
>
> [nltk_data]     Not allowed. [nltk_data] Error loading conll2000: HTTP
>
> Error 405: Not allowed. [nltk_data] Error loading movie_reviews: HTTP
>
> Error 405: Not allowed. Finished.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing `textblob` last day and it was giving an `error`. Then I tried other NLP module called `nltk`. But yesterday somehow it wasn't working for both of them. It was saying `error 405 : not allowed`. I looked for other posts but could not find anything.

When I tried today, surprisingly it started downloading the submodules. I think it was the server - `githubusercontent` issue from where it was trying to download the data from.

I am not sure if you'd face such errors but if you do, just try after sometime and hope it works for you too.

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

[image: textblob]

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

[image: nltk]